# How to delete obsolete Plunker versions?

Tags: plunker

Is there a way to delete obsolete [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) versions, but keep the latest version?

There are a few lines I pasted in the original version of my plunk that I would like to hide.

Comment: Obviously there is little interest in this feature - but I was looking for the same. This certainly discourages many people to make their Plunkers public.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to delete versions of a Plunk without deleting the entire Plunk.

Comment: Would be nice if this feature is added to the new `next.plnkr.co`